# Mac monitor connected, but not showing up in display settings

Tags: mac, display, settings

I accidentally rotated my external monitor 90 degrees and now the setting to switch it back is not showing up. My external monitor works, I can use it and see the desktop, but the Display Settings only have options to change my main screen's settings and not my second monitor. I've restarted the computer a few times and that has not helped. I also noticed the desktop image on the monitor is my old one, not the one I just changed it to...

Comment: How did you accidentally rotate the monitor ? physically or with software

Comment: In the display settings, I rotated the screen temporarily and cannot rotate it back now.